# IntelliJ Terminal Output Text Highlighting Blue

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, terminal, jetbrains-ide

I just recently installed IntelliJ and when running any commands in the terminal I get an annoying blue highlighting of the output. I can't see where this is happening in the settings, nor can I find a similar problem online.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have some custom colors set for screen text and background in Windows cmd console properties. See [IDEA-145236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145236) and [IDEA-124182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124182) for details. The solution is to set cmd console colors back to defaults - by either editing the registry key or by modifying default cmd console properties